# List of API client libraries grouped by programming language

Tags: discussion, libraries

This question serves as an organized reference of client libraries available for the Stack Exchange API. This is intended to be an all-inclusive list of libraries, so if you develop a library, feel free to insert it into the list below in the appropriate location. Each library is listed in alphabetical order under the language it is written / developed for.

```
Language       Name            API Version   Newest Release  
===========================================================  
ActionScript   ActionStack             1.0    July  9, 2010
-----------------------------------------------------------
C++            so++                    1.0    July 13, 2010 
-----------------------------------------------------------
D              Tangoverflow            1.0    June  1, 2010 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Java           StackExchange           1.0    July  8, 2010  
               stackoverflow-java-sdk  1.1    Feb. 18, 2011  
               StackWrap4J             1.0    July 26, 2010  
-----------------------------------------------------------
JavaScript     Soapi.JS                1.0    July 19, 2010  
               Soapi.JS 2              1.0    Sept 17, 2010  
               Stack.JS                2.0    Jan. 23, 2012  
               StackScript             1.0    July  9, 2010  
               StackUnderflow.js       1.0    Dec. 22, 2011  
-----------------------------------------------------------
.Net           BridgeStack             2.0    Jan. 22, 2012  
               Stacky                  2.0    Jan. 19, 2012  
               Soapi.CS                1.0    Sept 16, 2010  
-----------------------------------------------------------
Objective-C    CoreStack               1.0    Nov.  7, 2011  
               StackKit                1.0    Feb.  8, 2011  
               MSOEngine               1.0    June  4, 2010  
-----------------------------------------------------------
Perl           Net::StackExchange2     2.1    Feb.  3, 2013
----------------------------------------------------------
PHP            PHPstack                1.0    June 26, 2010  
               Stack.PHP               2.0    Feb.  5, 2012  
-----------------------------------------------------------
Python         Stack.PY                2.1    May  14, 2012  
               Py-StackExchange        1.1    Dec. 18, 2011  
               pyso.py                 1.0    Oct. 24, 2010  
               se-api-py               2.1    Feb. 26, 2013
               stack2py                2.1    Mar. 16, 2013
-----------------------------------------------------------
Ruby           Pilha                   1.1    Dec.  4, 2011  
               rubyoverflow            2.0    Jan.  3, 2012
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've done a PHP wrapper but don't have enough reputation to edit it in. Could someone link to it?

Comment: There you go. :)

Comment: Why's D in there?  And thanks for adding MSOEngine to the list whoever did it

Comment: @Matt: D needs a wrapper too. Every compiled language deserves a wrapper IMHO.

Comment: @George If somebody creates one for D I will learn D just to use it

Comment: @Thomas: I started a branch on Launchpad.  Only one file in, but I'll get back to it later today.

Comment: @dal: I added it.

Comment: @Thomas  It's ON!!!

Comment: What about plain C? I like C more than C++ oddly enough. Also where is the Assembly and Machine Code love?

Comment: @Earlz: I'll add it... but don't expect a lot of love... :)

Comment: yes, because somebody will write a library in assembly.  What I want is one for the TRS-80 :)

Comment: Well, if someone wrote a C library (I imagine the C++ one would be a pain to work with) you could call it from assembly. :) (Realistically, some call-out would be required anyway, so it's not cheating *that* much.)

Comment: Considering the only user of the assembly version would be Steve Gibson, I think it's OK to skip it...

Comment: Thanks whoever reformatted the page. I was going to do it myself anyway... now I don't have to.

Comment: @code: It's not the first time... look closely at the edit history.

Comment: Oy, good grief.

Comment: No updates for API version 2.2?