# Add List of Libraries to "Get Started" sidebar

Tags: feature-request

I suggest that a link to the [List of libraries](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-libraries) be added to the "Get Started" sidebar to provide a clear and obvious discovery path.

Answer (score 5):

You know where it would really be noticed? That little announcement strip at the top of the page under the logo.

Maybe:

> Writing an app? Check out the **list of libraries**.