# Where is the API located?

Tags: discussion, api, documentation

I want to know where is the API located and from where to download?

Comment: Well, the servers themselves are located in NY, IIRC.

Comment: @George: I meant the electronic form of data within the servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to your right------> (where it says Get Started)

Api is a REST implementation and as such has no 'download'

You may access it right from your browser address bar or leverage one of the many client libraries that have been implemented.

[List of API client libraries grouped by programming language](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-libraries)

If you are using JavaScript or C#, I would be remiss, as a library author, not to recommend the Soapi family of client libraries, but most all implementations are high quality.