# Net::StackExchange2 - Perl Wrapper for StackExchange API (it's on CPAN)

Tags: library, api-v2, perl

### About

This library is a little labour of love for two things dear to me : **StackOverflow**, a place where I've learned just so much, and **Perl** a cryptic language that's giving me perspective. I happen to be a long time C# developer so the whole thing was a -*learn a language by building stuff*- exercise. Any feedback and kind-insults are welcome. Please file them as issues on the github repository.

### Examples

The API is designed to be a one to one mapping with the methods in the documentation. It also has some conventions to make the interface intuitive. See the [documentation on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::StackExchange2), I've written examples and some design notes.

```
use Net::StackExchange2;
#For read-only methods.
my $se = Net::StackExchange2->new({site => 'stackoverflow'});

#OR

#for methods that require auth.
my $se = Net::StackExchange2->new(
    {site=>"stackoverflow", 
     access_token => '<THE ACCESS TOKEN>', 
     key => '<YOUR APP KEY>'
    }
);

my $ret =  $se->answers->answers_all({ order=> "desc", sort=>"votes" });
my $ret = $se->answers->answers(14586834);#pass one single ID
#or pass many in an array ref
my $ret = $se->answers->answers([4449779, 4477003]);

my $ret  = $se->search->search({tagged=>"perl"});

my $ret = $se->tags->tags_top_askers("perl", "month");

#filters are also supported. 

#This method gets comments from one user to another 
#and only retrives the body of the comment
my $ret = $se->users->
       users_comments_toid(368070,22656, {filter => '!mRNaB_KjjP'});
```

#### License

The library is licensed under the Bsd 3-clause. See [this for a quick english TL:DR](http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-3-clause-license-%28revised%29) about it.

#### Download

Ideally you don't need to download anything to use it with perl. [It's on CPAN here](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::StackExchange2). You just install it with cpan. Note it's **Net:StackExchange2** (2 at the end). *Net:StackExchange* is an older distribution for the 1.x API.

```
sudo cpan
>install Net::StackExchange2
```

### Contact

Contact me at *gideon [at] cpan [dot] org* for any issues with this distribution.

### Code

All of it is written in perl of course. Since I'm a beginner it might not be the best perl you've seen, I would be very happy to hear **any** suggestions/feedback.

The project is on github here: https://github.com/gideondsouza/perl-net-stackexchange

Please file any issues/bugs/features on the github page.

### Road Map

- Write some test cases.
- Implement better core abstractions with a test seam, so I can write unit tests to see whether each method generates the right url.

Comment: Finally I can add a Perl entry on [this page](http://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-api-client-libraries-grouped-by-programming-language)! Good job.

Comment: Thanks! :) I plan to write a couple updates for this api, to make it more fluent/intuitive, also plan to write a perl app that uses this wrapper :D